# Как тестировать js, html, css приложение на Smart TV?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как тестировать js, html, css приложение на Smart TV телевизоре? Как подключить приложение к телевизору и реально тестировать, а не под эмулятором?
Спасибо.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду нативное приложение под SmartTV или сайт в браузере?

Comment: Если вы имеете введу браузерное приложение, то если телевизор и компьютер который будет выступать в роле сервера подключены к одной сети, то это возможно, писал что-то подбное на C# когда сделать сайт внутри Wi-Fi сети, но там нету возможности работать со стилями и js, думаю стоит поискать похожий софт в интернете

Comment: @pavel1787mego почему? внутри локальное сетки все норм будет работать.

Comment: Я знаю, я говорю про то что когда я на C# писал локальный сервер, я его так криво написал что он только html страницы грузил, а то что другие пишут, то само сабой работать будет :D

Answer (score 3):

Статья от 2014 года — [Создание кроссплатформенного Smart TV приложения ... для Samsung, LG, Philips и других](https://habrahabr.ru/post/188294/).

Но смысл думаю будет понятен: многое зависит от производителя и года производства TV, на какой операционное системе (ОС) и версия ОС.

Можно использовать как **эмуляторы от производителя**, например, [TV Emulator](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-emulator).

**Так и «в боевых условиях», например:**

- [Testing Your Application on a TV for 2014](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/art00121/index)
- [Testing Your Application on a TV for 2013](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/d20/index)
- [Testing Your Application on a TV for 2011](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/art00013/index)

Можно пользоваться сервисами автоматизации, например, [Suitest](https://suite.st/).